# Create a centered navbar in bootstrap that stays in the same position with or without scrollbars

Tags: bootstrap-4, scroll, navbar, blazor, positioning

I really need some expertise here in my bootstrap 4.5 project :)

In Blazor, I have created the navbar menu in a separate component called `MainHeader`, and it just contains a standard navbar with basic setup according to all available examples out there. The navbar is positioned in the center as expected.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-customblue1">
    <div class="container" ">
        <a href="http://www.lindab.se" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="../img/logo.svg" />
        </a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The navbar is included in a Layout file that looks like this:

```
<MainHeader />

<div class="container content">
    @Body
</div>
```

Now to the thing that bothers me; when the page content shown fits the screen size, the content is placed in the center as expected, both the menu and the page content below. But when the page content below the menu is to big in terms of height, the scrollbar is introduced and that makes both the menu and page content 'jump' a bit to the left which isn't that good looking.

There is an understandable logic of course, but the question is, is there someone who knows a trick how to get this in the same position all the time?

Thanks for your time :)

/Henrik

Comment: You;d be better off putting the generated HTML in the question instead of showing Blazor layout - more people will be confident to try answering.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. When content is larger than the viewport, it scrolls. In order to prevent this you would need to set a custom size for your content container and only overflow scroll there.

```css
/* Remove default margin and padding for proper example render */

html,
body,
navbar,
main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

navbar {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  /* set height to be visible viewport, minus navbar height */
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.tall-content {
  display: block;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<navbar>Some navbar content</navbar>
<main class="content">
  <p class="tall-content">Some tall main content</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of my Layout's similar to your problem:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="wrap">

    <main>

        <aside>
            <NavMenu/>
        </aside>

        <article>
            @Body
        </article>

    </main>

</div>
```

`app.css`

```
:root {
    --main-bg-color: orange;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex
}

aside, article {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 2em
}

aside {
    max-width: 250px;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

article {
    flex: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    aside {
        flex: 1;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    main {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    aside {
        flex: none;
        max-width: unset;
        overflow-y: inherit;
    }
}
```